# Solving Liouville's Equation for the Harmonic Oscillator and Fluctuating energy

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am trying to solve the Liouville eqaution of the classic harmonic oscillator with fluctuating energy and arbitrary initial condition $\rho_0$. I want to approach the problem using the method of characteristics. So, given hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{1}{2}(p^2 + q^2)$$

In addition the expectation value of the Hamiltonian is $E(H) = U$ where $U$ is a constant. Now writing down the differential equations:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} - p\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial q} +q\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p} = 0$$

Now parameterizing the curve a long a trajectory $s$:

$$\frac{d t}{d s} = 1 \ ; \frac{d q}{d s} = -p \ ; \frac{d p}{d s} = q \ ; \frac{d \rho}{d s} = 0$$

Now solving these equation:

$$\begin{align}s =& \ t \\ \dot q =& -p \\ \dot p =& \ q \\ \rho_0 =& \ \rho(p_0,q_0,0) \end{align}$$

I can now substitute $s = t$, and can proceed to solve the coupled system of $\dot q = -p$ and $\dot  p = q$ and then rearrange for $p_0$ and $q_0$, to then substitute these into the equation for $\rho_0 = \rho(p_0,q_0,0)$. Taking the Ansatz $q(t) = A\sin(t) + B\cos(t)$ leads to:

\begin{align}q_0 =& \ q\cos(t) + p\sin(t) \\ p_0 =& \ q\sin(t) + p\cos(t) \end{align}

Now substituting into the initial condition $\rho_0(p_0,q_0)$:

$$\rho(p,q,t) = \rho_0(q\cos(t) + p\sin(t), q\sin(t) + p\cos(t))$$

I believe that this is the correct result for constant energy, and is also in agreement with other posts I have seen on Math/Physics Stackexchange.

My question now is: Is this the correct resulst even if the energy fluctuates? If not, what happens if the Hamiltonian is no longer constant, i.e. the energy fluctuates? Can my equation still be used?

Any help or hints would be appreciated!

**Edit**:

Maybe to further specify at what I would like to arrive: I would like to obtain an equilibrium distribution describing the various energies of the form:

$$\rho_{eq} = \frac{e^{- \beta H} }{\int dp \int dx e^{-\beta H}}$$

Comment: Your ansatz is wrong if the energy varies with time.

Comment: So what should my starting point be? Is there any way I can change my existing solution/work to account for varying energy?

Comment: You need to get a new Hamiltonian, one that doesn't conserve energy as a function of time. The solution strategy depends pretty heavily on what that new Hamiltonian looks like.

Comment: I don't think I have enough experience with constructing such Hamiltonians. Could you maybe describe what your approach would be?

Comment: One possibility is to change the potential from being constant in time to being time-dependent (in other words, change $q^2$ to something like $e^{-kt}q^2$).

Comment: That seems like an interesting change to the problem, thank you! Could one also approach the problem, by using the average of the different Hamiltonians, and then solving an "average" Hamiltonian which would be constant in energy?

Comment: How would one construct the ensemble of Hamiltonians over which you're taking the average? How do you determine how each particular Hamiltonian is weighted in that average?

Comment: The idea would be that I arrive at some form of equilibrium distribution of Hamiltonians in phase space (like the microcanonical ensemble), however I am not sure if that is possible or how to achieve that.